# Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol LCD_X_Config in Keil

Tags: symbol, error, keil

I encountered a problem working with the EMWIN package in keil, this error message:

```
. \ Objects \ test.axf: Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol LCD_X_Config (referenced from C: \ Keil_v5 \ ARM \ PACK \ Keil \ MDK-Middleware \ 6.2.0 \ emWin \ Lib \ ARM \ GUI_CM3_L.lib (gui_core.o ))
```

Application code is available at the following link:

https://www.4shared.com/s/f4miYaVFigm

you can see the error here:

[image: Undefined symbol LCD_X_Config]

Please give guidance if possible.
Thanks

Comment: make a search over your include directories and see where this symbol is defined. You are probably missing some include file.

Comment: I have checked but don't find any problem.